# Speed up the loading time for html, pdf and txt files within <object> tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, object, media

I have successfully embedded am html e-book in an object tag so that i can view it with my JQ Mobile app, its been successful but the problem is it's taking an average of 40 seconds to fully load, is there a way i can make it load faster? below is my code, further below are my scripts.

I have tried:

```
<div data-role="page" data-dom-cache="true">
```

no luck,
 any help is appreciated. Thank you. This is my code below.

```
<div data-role="page">
<div data-role"header"></div>

      <div data-role="content"> 

    <div data-role="collapsible-set">

        <div data-role="collapsible" data-icon="arrow-r">
                <h3>Agriculture <img src="images/icons/agriculture.png" 
                alt="agripic" id="listicon">
                </h3>
                        <ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true">

           <li>
                        <object data="data/test.html" type="application/html"  
                           width="100%" height="100%"  data-dom-cache="true">
                    <a href="agriculture/agriculture economics/agriculture.htm">Agriculture</a>
                        </object>
           </li>
    </div>

<link href="jquery.mobile-1.2.1.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style1.css">
<script src="jquery-1.6.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery.mobile-1.2.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various parameters on which a website optimization is depend, I can provide you a few suggestions:--

--> Always use your CSS library/code or JS code in the Header of your webpage

By that manner the css and JavaScript is speed loaded and then the rest of the web content is load, Also If the CSS code is not so lengthy, then use the actual code at the header side beside the importing CSS file from an another location, In importing and parsing a remote file will be take a long time to speed up.

--> Minify JavaScript, CSS, and HTML (in that order)

Minification is the process of removing unnecessary whitespace, returns, comments and other characters not necessary for functional code. Some minifiers like YUI Compressor go further by abbreviating local variable names with one- or two-character names. Minified code improves performance by downloading faster. Minified code also requires fewer TCP/IP packets, which requires fewer round trips for packets, speeding page display. See Velocity: TCP and the Lower Bound of Web Performance by Steve Souders.

--> Put JavaScript below CSS files

Placing JavaScript files after CSS files can block CSS files from downloading in parallel. To avoid this delay, place CSS files at the top, and JavaScript files after CSS or at the bottom of your HTML document.

-->Cache Resources Properly

Web caching stores frequently used objects closer to the client through browser, proxy, or server caches. By storing "fresh" objects closer to your users, you avoid round trips to the origin server, reducing bandwidth consumption, server load, and most importantly, latency. Many pages out on the web have poor caching policies in place, with static resources that have either no expiry headers set (freshness lifetimes), or short or expired expiry dates. This wastes bandwidth on repeat visits and visits to interior pages. Use long expiration dates for static resources, and configure etags properly. See the following tutorial for how to set proper caching policies, set expiration to at least 1 week (some webmasters use years) Localize External Resources for more details.

--> For object/flash part of the webpage

It is a media content, and it can be in a large size file, So the best way is that use the Customize Header Expiry/Caching, in which just load a slightly big amount of cache on the user side or just provide a valid expiration, so in future this will help you to load the content fast.

For more help See the below reference :--

[Reference 1](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/ultimate-guide-to-web-optimization-tips-best-practices/)

[Reference 2](http://www.websiteoptimization.com/speed/tweak/start-render/)